# HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, exception

I am new in java , jsp an I'm trying to print some data from Mysql database using an index.jsp. As the title says I'm getting an exception. I have checked for this exception a lot. I saw some same posts here in Stackoverflow but they did't help me. Here is my code:

**index.jsp :**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action ="New_printer.jsp" method="get">
    <input type ="submit" value="Proceed">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**New_printer.jsp :**

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%@ page import="com.results.Printer" %>

<%
int i;
ArrayList Rows = new ArrayList();

Rows = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("data");

for(i=1; i<Rows.size(); i++)
{
    ArrayList row = new ArrayList();

    row = (ArrayList) Rows.get(i);
    for(int j=1; j<4; j++)
    {
        String word =(String) row.get(j);
        out.print(word + " ");
    }
    out.println();  
}

%>

</body>
</html>
```

**Printer.java :**

```
package com.results;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Printer extends HttpServlet{

    private static Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs;



    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        resp.setContentType("text/jsp");

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tst","root","1234");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from test_db.person");

            ArrayList Rows = new ArrayList();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                ArrayList row =new ArrayList();
                for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
                {
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                Rows.add(row);
            }

            req.setAttribute("data", Rows);
            RequestDispatcher rqdp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/New_printer.jsp");
            rqdp.forward(req, resp);

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**web.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Simple_Print</display-name>
  <!-- 
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>printer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.results.Printer</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>printer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> -->

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**EXCEPTION**

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

type Exception report

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:548)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.New_005fprinter_jsp._jspService(New_005fprinter_jsp.java:123)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:431)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.20 logs.
```

Can you help? Please I'm stack here for days.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Jens No , It is not duplicate with your link. It is server code error with NPE.

Comment: status code **500** means Internal server error and error was as you said *NullPointerException* . Can you post error log ? Did you get connection manager well ?

Comment: I use tomcat-apache 8.0 running in localhost. I can go in my index.jsp but when i click on submit button it shows me the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are submitting form from `index.jsp` to  `New_printer.jsp` but you haven't passed `data` attribute so `request.getAttribute("data");` will give you null pointer.

What you are doing:

`index.jsp`----->`New_printer.jsp`

What you should do:

`index.jsp`----->`Printer.java`------->`New_printer.jsp`

Comment: I see your point. I have "req.setAttribute("data", Rows);" in .java. How can i contact them? I mean the .jsp with the . java.

Comment: @ΝίκοςΔιαμαντόγιαννης change form action in index.jsp to servlet url

Comment: My servlet-url is index.jsp.

Comment: @ΝίκοςΔιαμαντόγιαννης No it cant be(same url different page) create  servlet mapping in web.xml

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will do some changes using your advice. I understand now my mistake. I will mark yor answer. When I solve it i wil rewrite the code.

Comment: FINALLY IT'S ALIVE!!! Thanks a lot , your advice helped. I can't update my code. I changed everything.